# Oracle Apex to store select list display value in column

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an IG query:

```
select emp_id, dept_id , emp_name, designation, bu from employees;
```

Here dept_id is a select list query:

```
select dept_name d, dept_id r from departments;
```

In my IG i want to add a hidden column that would store the display value of dept_id,i.e. dept_name value as well.

How can i formulate the query for the same?

In future i might need to add authorization related conditions and there i would need dept_name value. So i want another column dept_name in IG query to store the display value.

Answer (score 0):

If "store" means "store into a newly added column in `employees` table", then that would be wrong - data model wouldn't be normalized and there's no real benefit in doing that.

There should be referential integrity constraint between `employees` and `departments` established via `dept_id` columns that exists in both tables.

---

On the other hand, if "store" means that you need a non-database column in interactive grid, then you could e.g. create a function that returns department name:

```
create or replace function f_dept_name (par_dept_id in departments.dept_id%type)
  return departments.dept_name%type
is
  retval departments.dept_name%type;
begin
  select d.dept_name
    into retval
    from departments d
    where d.dept_id = par_dept_id;

  return retval;
end;
```

and include it into current query:

```
select e.emp_id, 
       e.dept_id,
       f_dept_name (e.dept_id) dept_name,     --> here
       e.emp_name, 
       e.designation, 
       e.bu 
from employees e;
```

Set it to be *hidden*, if you don't want to display it (and you don't because LOV already shows department name).

But, once again, that's most probably not the way to go.